# Django Rest Framework Handle a lot of Request & Responses with put method for text editor

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, put

I Have a Text Editor in FrontEnd And I want to save text changes as soon as I stop typing
but requests and responses are a lot
I want to handle this problem with best way
Do you know a solotion or package for handling this?
thank you

Answer (score 0):

You need to handle in Frontend. It can be solved by using debounce.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/debounce
For example, you can make api request after 1 second from stop typing.

Answer (score 0):

Use Web-sockets to handle real time updates , Django has a cool package for this specific use case [Django channels](https://channels.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)